# How to use current date in logstash config file as input file

Tags: date, logstash, config

I am trying to process a file in Logstash with the current date in the name *"YYYYMMDD.json"*. However I can't use the date variable in this config file. Is it possible to still do this without hardcoding the date?

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/home/ubuntu/YYYYMMDD.json
                        type => "ip-address"
                        start_position => "beginning"
                        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["IP:Port"]
                        index => "results"
                        document_id => "%{ip}"
                        doc_as_upsert => true
                        action => "update"
                        retry_on_conflict => 10
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `path` you are missing a `"` at the end of the path:

```
path => "/home/ubuntu/YYYYMMDD.json"
```

Try this

```
file {
    path => "/home/ubuntu/%{+YYYYMMDD}.json"
    type => "ip-address"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
```

You can use:  `path => "/home/ubuntu/*.json"` and parse all JSON in the folder.

You can use [filebeats](https://www.elastic.co/fr/products/beats/filebeat) if you add a file every day.